# Node.js start a program as admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have written a program in C# that requires administrator privileges to run, I also have an electron app which needs to execute the C# exe file.
In the C# manifest I made it auto run as admin but when all the files are packaged together to be downloaded by windows it does not have the auto run as admin prompt.

As a result of this I need to be able to execute the exe file from node.js as an admin, so far I have this;

```js
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
    exec('Test.exe', function(err, data) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(data.toString());                       
    });
```

Comment: Execute Node in a console window that's launched as admin?

Comment: That doesn't work because it executed the C# program without admin and so wont run properly

Comment: To be clear you have a **packaged** Electron app that runs `Test.exe`, but you want to run `Test.exe` as administrator? If so, then how are you packaging your app? E.g. `electron-builder`, `electron-packager`, `electron-winstaller`, etc...

Comment: It is packaged using electron-packager, I have set the electron app to run as admin but when I package into appx it doesn't work as expected

Comment: First, open cmd as admin. Then run node start program command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running as administrator is possible with `electron-builder` only on Windows.

Just set this option in your `package.json`:

```
"build": {
    "win": {
        "requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator"
    }
}
```

Now your entire Electron app will run as administrator, allowing you to run your `Test.exe` as administrator as well.

Note: this only works with `electron-builder`, not `electron-packager`.

Read more about [`requestedExecutionLevel`](https://www.electron.build/configuration/win).